# Which are the $\max$ and $\min$'s of $\frac{\sin{2t}}{2}$, $t \in [0, 2\pi]$?

Tags: trigonometry, maxima-minima

I have to find the max and mins of:

$f(x,y) = xy $ in set $ x²+y²<=1$

After derivating and finding $(0,0)$ as saddle point by hessian...
and testing the border:

$x = cost$, $y = sentf(cost,sent) = 1/2.sin(2t)..$

Wich are the max and mins of $(1/2)*sin(2t)$, $0<=t<=2pi$?

I know that critical points are $t = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $t = \frac{3\pi}{4}$
But the book shows $t = \frac{5\pi}{4}$ and $t = \frac{7\pi}{4}$ critical points too.Why? Someone can help?

Thanks!

Comment: Because $\sin(2t)$ is $\pi$-periodic. Also, AM-GM in the beginning gives an immediate result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in [Maximilian Janisch](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631742/maximilian-janisch)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3560304/wich-are-the-max-and-mins-of-1-2sin2t-0-t-2pi/3560313#comment7320786_3560304), since $\sin(x)$ is periodic with period $2\pi$, you have that $\sin(2t)$ is periodic with period $\frac{2\pi}{2} = \pi$.

Thus, the values of $\sin(2t)$ for $t = \frac{\pi}{4}$ and $t = \frac{5\pi}{4} = \frac{\pi}{4} + \pi$ are the same, with both giving $\sin(2t) = 1$, so $\frac{\sin(2t)}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ is a maximum at both points. Also, those for $t = \frac{3\pi}{4}$ and $t = \frac{7\pi}{4} = \frac{3\pi}{4} + \pi$ are the same, with both giving $\sin(2t) = -1$, so $\frac{\sin(2t)}{2} = -\frac{1}{2}$ is a minimum at both points. Also, finally note that $\frac{5\pi}{4} \in [0,2\pi]$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4} \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. I was thinking that the limitation 0<=t<=2pi didnt let 5pi/4 and 7pi/4 be answer. But they are pi periodic like you and maximilian said.

Comment: @FELINTONETO You're welcome. I added to the answer the point you raised, i.e., that both $\frac{5\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ are between $0$ and $2\pi$.

Comment: When I was calculating for some reason i found 5pi/4 and 7pi/4 > 2pi...this was driving me crazy..and now i realize it was wrong..hahah..